# Vue Apollo: variables are not added to graphql query, or I am not correctly accepting them on the backend (Golang)

Tags: go, graphql, vue-apollo

I cannot seem to get variables in a graphql query made with apollo into the query body to be accepted into backend server.

I have a simple vue frontend and go backend.  In a vue-component I have the following query:

```
apollo: {
    entry: {
      query: gql`
        query variables($userID: Int){
          entries(userID: $userID) {
            id,
            value,
            timeStamp
          }
        }
      `,
      variables() {
        return {
          userID: 2
        }
      },

      update: data => data,
    }
  }
}
```

On my go backend I nave the handler function for all POST requests

```
// GraphQL returns an http.HandlerFunc for our /graphql endpoint
func (s *Server) GraphQL() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //Allow CORS here By * or specific origin
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
        // Check to ensure query was provided in the request body
        if r.Body == nil {
            http.Error(w, "Must provide graphql query in request body", 400)
            return
        }

        var rBody reqBody
        // Decode the request body into rBody
        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&rBody)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "Error parsing JSON request body", 400)
        }

        fmt.Println(rBody.Query)

        // Execute graphql query
        result := gql.ExecuteQuery(rBody.Query, *s.GqlSchema)

        // render.JSON comes from the chi/render package and handles
        // marshalling to json, automatically escaping HTML and setting
        // the Content-Type as application/json.
        render.JSON(w, r, result)
    }
}
```

When I run the query, I am returned {"entries" : null}.  When I print out the query that was sent to my go server, I get the following:

```
query variables($userID: Int) {
  entries(userID: $userID) {
    id
    value
    timeStamp
    __typename
  }
}
```

In line 2 of this I would hope to see entries(userID: 2).  Indeed, if I remove the variables from my query made in vue, and hardcode the userID in the query, everything works.

I checked to make sure the variable is being sent in someway, which if I look at the POST request made it has the following in the parameters:

```
operationName   variables
query   query variables($userID: Int) { entries(userID: $userID) { id value timeStamp __typename } }
variables   {…}
userID  2
```

Am I not accepting the data correctly on my backend, as the variable userID is being sent in the POST request?

**Solution:** Thanks to @cgcgbcbc for the solution.  My `reqBody` struct was the following:

```
type reqBody struct {
    Query     string                 `json:"query"`
}
```

When it should be:

```
type reqBody struct {
    Query     string                 `json:"query"`
    Variables map[string]interface{} `json:"variables"`
}
```

Then I just needed to pass `rBody.Variables` to my `ExecuteQuery` function as in his solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, the data receiving in your backend is correct, the query itself does not contain the query parameter, the query parameter is sent via `variables` key.

The response issue is this line `result := gql.ExecuteQuery(rBody.Query, *s.GqlSchema)`.
`variables` from the request body need also be passed to `ExecuteQuery`. An example implementation using `graphql-go/graphql` `Do` function can be

```
func executeQuery(query string, schema graphql.Schema, variables map[string]interface{}) *graphql.Result {
    result := graphql.Do(graphql.Params{
        Schema:        schema,
        RequestString: query,
        VariableValues: variables
    })
    if len(result.Errors) > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("errors: %v", result.Errors)
    }
    return result
}
```

And an example of type `reqBody` can be

```
type reqBody struct {
    Query string
    Variables map[string]interface{}
}
```

Then `json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&rBody)` will automatically set Query and Variables

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I believe the only thing holding me from solving this now is how to get the `rBody.Variables`.  That is, go is informing me that type `reqBody` doesn't have a field `Variables`.  I've been searching for a while to no avail; do you know explicitly how to retrieve the variables from an http.Request?

Comment: @EnigmaTaco what is the type declaration of struct reqBody? It is possible that you need declare this field in reqBody.

Comment: reqBody only has one field: `type reqBody struct {Query string `json:"query"`}` (I believe this is from the `http` package).  I suppose my confusion right now is "How do I take my variables from my POST request (made with apollo) and put them into a variable of type `map[string]interface` to pass to `ExecuteQuery` from your answer?"

Comment: @EnigmaTaco I don't think it is from `http` package, if so, it should be named `ReqBody`. However, note that `json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&rBody)` does not require `rBody` be a certain type, you can declare your own type, for example `MyReqBody`, which has the desired field, then use it as the type of `rBody` and it will have those values after decoding `r.Body`

Comment: You were absolutely right!  I apologize as I'm still quite new to Go.  I just needed to add the field `Variables map[string]interface{} \`json:"variables"\`` to the struct `reqBody` (which I incorrectly though was built into the http package), then passed `rBody.Variables` to my `ExecuteQuery` function as in your answer.